# Clean urls with apache htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I convert this url

```
 http://example.com/vpage/page.php?number=1&status=completed
```

into a clean like this

```
 http://example.com/1/completed
```

so that in my php page I can echo variables 1 and completed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0]+)/?$ /vpage/page.php?number=$1&status=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```